# Сравнение строк в Java по ссылке

Tags: java

Во многих книгах по `java` (например, "Философия Java") пишут, что при написании конструкции вида `String s = "some string"` на самом деле происходит создание нового объекта `String`, примерно так: `String s = new String("some string")`.

Почему тогда я делаю `System.out.println(new String("a") == new String("a"))` и получаю `false`. Но в случае `System.out.println("a" == "a")` получаю `true`.

Почему в первом случае `jvm` создала два разных объекта, а во втором ссылается на один и тот же ?

Comment: Рекомендую https://habrahabr.ru/post/79913/

Comment: @iksuy уже читаю :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если вы используете явный вызов `new`, то создается новый объект. НО если вы используете не явное создание объекта, то компилятор помещает его в специальное хранилище - [пул строк](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BB_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA) и поэтому при последующих неявных созданиях объекта он берется от туда.

Вы можете поместить строку в пул используя метод `intern`, но не помещайте туда все строки подряд, так как это не дает значительного прироста производительности и может вызвать переполнение памяти (OutOfMemoryError).

[Вот](https://habrahabr.ru/post/79913/) статья об этом.

Comment: Такое правило общее для большества компиляторов или это особенность `jvm` ?

Comment: и вместо new String("some string") на самом деле происходит new String("some string").intern(). System.out.println(new String("a").intern() == new String("a").intern()); дает результат true

Comment: @faoxis Это не особенность jvm, это называется Java Memory Model

Comment: @DaysLikeThis пул интернированных строк не имеет никакого отношения к JMM

Comment: @etki Есть куча, в ней есть пул строк. Делая интерн, мы получаем указатель на строку, которая лежит в этом пуле.

Comment: @DaysLikeThis все верно, но JMM не про это. JMM - про гарантии в concurrent коде.

Comment: Эта особенность не JVM, а конкретно компиляторов Java, описана в [Java Language Specification §3.10.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5).