# По каким критериям в Java строка попадает в пул строк?

Tags: java

По сути этот вопрос продолжает [другой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/714949/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-java-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5?noredirect=1#comment1072810_714949).

Во многих [статьях](https://habrahabr.ru/post/79913/) говорится, что при создании строк без `new` через литерал строка попадает в пул строк. В противном случае необходим метод `intern`. Как тогда объяснить поведение ниже ?

```
    String s2 = "hello";
    String s1 = "hello";
    System.out.println(s1 == s2); // true

    System.out.println("hel" + "lo" == "hello"); // true

    s1 = "hello";
    s2 = "hel";
    String s3 = "lo";

    System.out.println(s1 == s2 + s3); // false
    System.out.println(s2 + s3 == "hel" + "lo"); //false
```

Если в последнем случае `s2` ссылается туда же куда и литерал "hel", и с `s3` такая же история, то почему `"hel" + "lo"` не равно (по ссылке) `s2 + s3` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка может попасть в пул констант в двух случаях:

1. На этапе компиляции.

Компилятор проходит по всем строкам в исходном коде и добавляет их в пул констант. Если в коде есть какие-то места, в которых нужны вычисления и компилятор может их произвести, то он делает это. В Вашем примере это `System.out.println("hel" + "lo" == "hello");`. Сконкатенировал `"hel" + "lo"` и положил в пул.

2. Вызов String.intern()

[Описание метода (ссылка на документацию)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29). 
Здесь надо обязательно указать **границы применения** данного способа. Данный методы выглядит очень заманчиво: "мы можем сократить использование памяти, и производительность в програме!! Это громадная оптимизация!!"

- Из intern пула НЕ возможно удалить данные
- intern медленнее чем реализация (через ConcurrentHashMap, например) интернирования. Потому что во внутренней таблице (в которой хранятся интерниованные строки) всего около 60 000 бакетов и большОе количество строк может забить эти бакеты. Покачто эта Map не ресайзится.
- intern может влиять на работу всей JVM так как таблица используется для хранения информации о классах

Если мне не верите, то [Алексею Шипилеву](https://youtu.be/SZFe3m1DV1A?t=32m00s) должны поверить (про intern с 32 минуты).

Comment: Не понимаю. Если `intern` такой перегруженный, то почему в него кладутся ВСЕ литералы ???

Comment: Заполнить его до состояния "тормозов" это минимум от 100к уникальных стрингов. Просто при использовании данного метода надо очень хорошо знать и понимать как он работает и нужен ли он Вам.

Answer (score 4):

Строка попадет в пул строк только после вызова [метода intern класса String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--).

Детально про строковые литералы из спецификации [на английском](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)

По поводу "hel" + "lo" - это строковая константа

Возьмем класс

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s2 = "hel";
        String s3 = "lo";

        System.out.println(s2 + s3 == "hel" + "lo");
    }
```

Скомпилируем и посмотрим его декомпилятором

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s2 = "hel";
    String s3 = "lo";
    System.out.println(s2 + s3 == "hello");
}
```

Компилятор собрал "hel" + "lo" в одну строку, что бы доказать это, посмотрим байткод:

```
public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 6 L0
    LDC "hel"
    ASTORE 1
   L1
    LINENUMBER 7 L1
    LDC "lo"
    ASTORE 2
   L2
    LINENUMBER 9 L2
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    NEW java/lang/StringBuilder
    DUP
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/StringBuilder.<init> ()V
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    ALOAD 2
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
    LDC "hello"
    IF_ACMPNE L3
    ICONST_1
    GOTO L4
   L3
   FRAME FULL [[Ljava/lang/String; java/lang/String java/lang/String] [java/io/PrintStream]
    ICONST_0
   L4
   FRAME FULL [[Ljava/lang/String; java/lang/String java/lang/String] [java/io/PrintStream I]
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Z)V
   L5
    LINENUMBER 10 L5
    RETURN
   L6
    LOCALVARIABLE args [Ljava/lang/String; L0 L6 0
    LOCALVARIABLE s2 Ljava/lang/String; L1 L6 1
    LOCALVARIABLE s3 Ljava/lang/String; L2 L6 2
    MAXSTACK = 3
    MAXLOCALS = 3
}
```

"hello" представлена константой, s2 + s3 собираются через StringBuilder и преобразуются в строку через toString(), соответственно это 2 разных объекта, и при сравнении указателей будет false

Comment: Цитата из статьи: "Все строки-константы, которые встречаются в классе автоматически интернированы." Без всяких `intern`.

Comment: @faoxis из спецификации: Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.  (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.3)

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос: "Если в последнем случае s2 ссылается туда же куда и литерал "hel", и с s3 такая же история, то почему "hel" + "lo" не равно (по ссылке) s2 + s3" ?

Comment: Почему тогда `"hel" + "lo" == "hello"`?

Comment: @diraria слив засчитан :) "hel" + "lo" это constant expressions = new String("hello").intern()

Comment: Ну да. Вот и напишите об этом в ответе, желательно поподробней. Вопрос хороший, можно и ответ развёрнутый написать :)